# Piratebay ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: google-chrome, dns, ssl, ssl-certificate

Since a few months ago I've been using proxy sites to access the pirate bay, but now I'm in need to create an account, and those proxy sites won't allow me to do that.

The problem is because TPB is giving me an SSL error.

ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

I already did what's described here: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/disabling-browser-support-ssl-v3.htm

And I dont have "minimum SSLv3 version support" in my Chrome version.

I'm running Windows XP in this machine, but I'm not allowed to upgrade it (I don't have human permission :] ) My problem is described here: http://tehnoblog.org/google-chrome-error-err_ssl_version_or_cipher_mismatch/

I've already followed all the steps that I found on the web, I even flushed the DNS, so what should I try now?

Comment: You are limited to the cipher suites that Windows XP supports.  Which of course is the entire problem with Windows XP and reason Google and Mozilla have planned not to support it eventually.

Answer (score 0):

<s>If you’re using a “web proxy”, they perform sort-of a MITM attack. That means the SSL/TLS connection isn’t terminating at your browser, but at the proxy service. The only thing you can do is contact the support of that proxy service and explain the issue.</s>

It appears Google Chrome uses Windows’ built-in encryption functions. Windows XP can’t do elliptic curve cryptography. Use Firefox instead, it uses a different encryption library that’s platform-independent.

Comment: Nope, I'm trying direct access.

Comment: @MatheusLopes Answer updated. You should probably remove the proxy stuff from your question if it isn’t used here.